# Low Rank Approximation of Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I understand the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) is often used to compute the best **rank r approximation** of a matrix A. However, are there methods other than computing the SVD that would allow one to compute a low rank approximation of a given matrix?

Comment: [Principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is the data analysis technique that comes from using the SVD-based low rank approximation to the matrix of interest (generated from the data set). [Exploratory factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_factor_analysis), by contrast, describes a family of methods that produce a similar approximation, not necessarily using SVD.

Comment: A more recent development in data science is the [CUR decomposition](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0803205106). It similarly produces a low rank approximation, but aims to build factor matrices consisting of actual rows/columns from the original matrix.